# MySQL Lock - Update - Unlock

Tags: php, mysql, locking

I am trying to update the money amount in my table (mysql innodb):

> UPDATE money SET amount = amount+150 WHERE rowid=1;

Question:

1. Is it safe enough when more than one process doing it at the very same time?
2. Do I need to put it inside transaction? Or don't have to?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying multiple connections will be amending the `amount` of the same row i.e. the one pointed to be `rowid=1` all at the same time?

Comment: A single statement, is still an innodb transaction with all its benefits.

Comment: @danblack thanks for the confirmation...

Comment: @RiggsFolly it is theoretically possible...